# Reason for syntax error in conditional statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have one check_box in form:

```
<%= f.check_box :user, {checked: true if current_user.id == "1"} %>
```

and here I'm getting syntax error, while here:

```
<%= f.check_box :user, {checked: if current_user.id == "1"
                                   true
                                  end} %>
```

everything works fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clarify the sentence:

```rb
<%= f.check_box :user, {checked: (true if current_user.id == "1")} %> 
# or maybe...
<%= f.check_box :user, {checked: true if (current_user.id == "1")} %>
```

Btw, you don't need the `if`, just the result of the condition. Try:

```rb
<%= f.check_box :user, {checked: (current_user.id == 1)} %>
```

Comment: You also don't need the `{ }` if it's the last argument you're passing